# Create phpmyadmin stored routine to import a local csv file

Tags: import, phpmyadmin

For my company, I regularly update our website by uploading/ importing several local csv files into our website dbase using phpmyadmin.

It would be a great savings of time to create a "routine" that saved all the steps of the import. But I am not enough of a programmer to figure it out.  Can someone help me on this?

Thank you in advance.

I tried to find the sql string that represented the steps of the csv import but cannot find if/where such a code is created/ stored.  In the routine, I attempted some LOAD and INSERT INTO statements but got nowhere and the resulting error messages were too cryptic to help me.  Searched far and wide for code snippets online to no avail.